# Where can I find a complete set of Ante-Nicene Writings?

Tags: early-church, church-fathers, resource-request

I am a self-learner and am really interested in the writings of the Christian fathers during the Ante-Nicene period.  I found an great e-book for a few dollars titled "The Complete Ante-Nicene Church Fathers Collection [9 volumes]", and I also found a set of books called "The Early Church Fathers, 38 Volumes."  I'm just not sure whether either of these contains all of the writings found during that period or just a selection of them.  What I'd really like to have is a list of all of the writings discovered during this period, but I can't seem to find it.  Are any of you aware of such a list?  I hope this isn't too loaded a question.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). I, too, would be interested to know if there is such a list, or if it *is* a loaded question, what are the various lists. For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not free, and it's not complete, but [*The Fathers of the Church: A New Translation*](https://www.hfsbooks.com/series/fathers-of-the-church-patristic-series/) is the closest thing to a complete set of the writings of the church fathers that I've seen in English.  It includes over 120 volumes of writings, though many of these relate to the post-Nicene period.   It's frequently cited by other works, like the [*Ancient Christian Commentary on Scripture*](https://www.ivpress.com/accs/).

I've often turned to it when the out-of-copyright *Ante-Nicene Fathers* simply doesn't provide the material I'm looking for, like [Origen's *Commentary on Romans*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3E9VjfiXWz0C).  And I find that the translation is usually better, both in accuracy and readability.

As mentioned, the volumes aren't free online, but thankfully many pages are accessible through Google Books – Origen's commentary linked above can be previewed on Google Books, at least in the USA.

Comment: I got an error on your link (cua.edu forwards to catholic.edu, but the cuapress subdomain does not resolve). I found a Chinese Orthodox web page (http://www.orthodox.cn/patristics/frchurchnewtrans_en.htm) which lists volumes 1 to 45 of a set, apparently all linked to archive.org. Is this the set? My guess was that at least volumes 1 to 45 are out of copyright, and now available online in some form.

Comment: @disciple Thanks, I've fixed the link.  The site you give refers to the same books, but they aren't out of copyright... if I click on the links to archive.org, I get a "this book is restricted" message.  Perhaps there's a way to use archive.org to read them, but they aren't out of copyright yet.

Comment: I can't find a neat list anywhere, and using your link it's quite hard to find the oldest volumes. I tried Amazon with the old name, and if I add a single volume number, it apparently can find any volume up to 65. Would sure be nice to have an in-order list.

Comment: @disciple Yeah, not sure why they display it like that.  [Logos](https://www.logos.com/product/33665/fathers-of-the-church-series) provides a list broken down by era, but it's still not in publication order.

Answer (score 9):

Unless I am mistaken, there has never been an English translation set that encompasses **absolutely all** the ante-Nicene writings. Most people use [ccel.org](http://www.ccel.org/fathers.html) to read the *Ante-Nicene Fathers* edited by James Donaldson and Alexander Roberts which, unless I am mistaken, is the most comprehensive English translation set of the ante-Nicene writings. If you want to compile a list of all the ante-Nicene writings, you would probably need to resort to reviewing Jacques Paul Migne’s *Patrologiæ Cursus Completus: Series Græca* (161 vol.) and *Series Latina* (220 vol.), but of course, you need to know Greek and Latin.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I've been there, glad to know it has credibility. I would definitely like to find a list of all, whether they have been translated into English or not, just to have as reference. In the process of learning Greek by the way!  I can pronounce decently, but I have a long way to go with grammar and definitions. Im alsi fluent in German, so perhaps I could find some of these other writings translated into German even if they aren't in English. Just want a master list for reference.  Thank you for the other references. I'll look into those.

Answer (score 0):

They are available for free with the free download of e-sword:

http://www.e-sword.net/

This is an excellent tool with many free resources included.